# Sudden massive system temperature spike

Tags: graphics-card, temperature, overheating, heatsink

I was having a problem with my computer instantly shutting down while playing graphic intensive games with my new GPU. It was suggested that I use a temp monitor bc overheating was suspect. While using the temp monitor It was going very smooth. It started at about 28 and rose a degree every 3 minutes or so until it leveled out at about 37.(This is all while playing the game) Then all of a sudden it went from 37 to 127 in the span of about 8 seconds and crashed before I could even exit out of the game.

My personal thoughts are a bug somewhere I can't find that is tricking the computer into thinking it is overheating. I have already reloaded my original bios and drivers.

Note: This is not a spike in the CPU temp. It only shows it in the system temp....

Any help would be appreciated

Edit: The only thing hot to the touch is the heatsink sitting on top of the chipset. Even after spike occured

Comment: Do you have a screenshot from the temperature monitoring program? You mentioned "system" and CPU temp but have you checked **GPU** temperature? Also, are you sure your PSU is sufficient for the new graphics card?

Comment: 127 128 and 255 & 256 type of numbers on a sencor reading are often out of range, or the software not reading it correct. All this software for reading temps are highly dependant on the hardware putting out that info and software interpreting it correct. It may have very well been anywhere. Not everything has a sencor on it besides.  Ex: core temp readers dont work ony my gig board, showing ~35 when the cpu is pushing 80+. Does the manufacture provide temperature monitoring utilities?  Even using them a soft or hard glitch could present any numbers. An IR thermal probe would tell you more.

Comment: Unless a heat sink is totally loose or there is no thermal goop on it, your "last real readings" prior to fail, should be good enough to know if the fails were temperature based problems. Monitoring the temps to see IF it is going badly in that area like your doing, is a good way to troubleshoot. It is also nice to have done the monitoring when the system is normal, so you know what "normal" is , what software works correct, and how that software fails.  What are the results of the rest of your temperature monitoring?

Answer (score 0):

Your question and your edit .... "Edit: The only thing hot to the touch is the heatsink sitting on top of the chipset. ...." suggests that your cooling system is not working properly. Although t is impossible to be sure without more information, it sounds as if a fan is seized and probably needs replacing.

Comment: Which fan? There isn't one on the chipset and all fans are actually spinning freely. What more information do you need? I will do my best to provide it. Also, sitting idle my system stays at 28 and has been this entire time. Would a faulty fan account for such a sudden and large spike?

Comment: @Ramhound: ????????

Comment: I believe that yes, a faulty fan would, even if it is intermittent.

Comment: @Ramhound: Please read your comment. The word "hot" does not appear. :)